# Single exe text editor

Tags: windows, software-rec, text-editors

I'm looking for a *single exe* text editor, similar to Notepad.

I don't need any fancy features, as long as it's a single exe file that doesn't need to be installed and can run from the desktop or a flash drive.

Comment: Are you looking for features that aren't offered by Notepad and Wordpad, and if so, which?

Answer (score 7):

[Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html), because it's simple.

[image]

Comment: +1; It also has an option to completely replace notepad on your system, which is really good as I'm in the habit of typing [WIN]+[R] notepad [ENTER], to launch notepad(2).

Answer (score 4):

### Notepad++

I think one of the most powerful text editors out there is **Notepad++**, which also has a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable).

> Notepad++ Portable is the handy Notepad++ text editor packaged as a portable app so you can do your development on the go. It has all the same great features of Notepad++ including support for multiple languages and an extensive plugin system, but there's nothing to install.

[image]

### EditPad Lite

Also, there's [**EditPad Lite**](http://www.editpadlite.com/), which has a portable installation option.

> EditPad Lite is a general-purpose text editor, designed to be small and compact, yet offer all the functionality you expect from a basic text editor.

[image]

I've used both, but generally I definitely prefer Notepad++ because it's very feature rich.

Answer (score 1):

I use this all the time, "Win32Pad" http://www.gena01.com/win32pad/ .

I have not used this, but if I were to give up on Win32Pad (never!), then I would look into this one, "Metapad" http://liquidninja.com/metapad/ .

Answer (score 0):

SciTE is the one I have been using for a very long time now. Simple text editor with syntax highlighting for virtually every programming language out there, column edit and lots of other things.

> [A single file executable called Sc1](http://www.scintilla.org/Sc357.exe) (750K) does not need any DLL or properties files as these are linked into the executable. You may still create properties files if you wish